# Number of trees $T = (V,E) \;$ such that $V = \left \{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 \right \} \;$, $\deg(1) = 2$ , $\deg(t)<5 \;\forall\; 2\leq t\leq 7$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

I tried summing all of the cases (I found 4), but somehow i'm getting the wrong answer.

For ex. the number of trees on 7 vertices such that the following sequence is the sequence of their degrees:

My solution (wrong) using [Cayley's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_formula):

The only possible degree sequences are:

$(2,1,1,2,2,2,2) = \binom{5}{1}*\binom{6}{4}$

$(2,3,2,2,1,1,1) = \binom{5}{2}*6\binom{5}{2}$

$(2,3,3,1,1,1,1) = \binom{5}{2,2}*\binom{6}{2}$

$(2,4,2,1,1,1,1) = \binom{5}{3}*6*4$

What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you mind to tell us the "correct" answer?

Comment: @RobertZ 6450..

Comment: @RobertZ Would you mind telling why my application of  Cayley's formula does't work?

Comment: Cayley's formula (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley-Formel) gives $7^{7-2}=7^5=16807$, which is the number of all possible trees, that have $7$ vertices. We don't want to have them all. We want only some of them, which have specific properties, that are asked in the question. http://www.biomath.nyu.edu/oldrag/tree/rna_database/7vertices.html

Comment: @We know though that the number of trees such that the sequence of their vertices degress is $(d_1,....d_m)\;$ and $d_1 + ... + d_m = 2n-2\;$ is $\binom{n-2}{d_1-1,...,d_m-1}\;$ and that's exactly what I applied here.

Comment: @RobertZ, look at my last comment please.

Comment: Then it should be $(2,1,1,2,2,2,2)\to5!\binom{6}{4}=1800$ which is the same of my $5\cdot \frac{6!}{2}$.

Comment: @RobertZ Why the $5!$?

Comment: It comes from $\binom{n-2}{d_1-1,...,d_m-1}$.

Comment: @RobertZ but $\binom{n-2}{d_1-1,...,d_m-1} = \binom{7-2}{1,1,1,1,1} = \binom{5}{1}$

Comment: No, $\binom{7-2}{1,1,1,1,1} =\frac{5!}{1!1!1!1!1!}=5!$

Comment: @RobertZ, Oh lord. mistake found. thanks alot

Comment: Fine! Sorry, but I have to go. Compare your calculations with mine below. I am sure you will get the right answer now.

Answer (score 2):

The unlabelled trees with $7$ vertices are[image]
We have to rule out the last three which have a vertex of degree $\geq 5$ or no vertex of degree $2$.

So for each of the $8$ cases we compute the number of labelled trees such that
 $\deg(1) = 2$ and $\deg(t)<5 \;\forall\; 2\leq t\leq 7$ and we add them  all together:
$$5\cdot \frac{6!}{2}+3\cdot\frac{6!}{2}+3\cdot 6!+3\cdot\frac{6!}{3!}+1\cdot \frac{6!}{2^3}+1\cdot\frac{6!}{2}+2\cdot\frac{ 6!}{3!}+2\cdot\frac{6!}{2^2}=6450.$$
Each term is obtained as the number of vertices of degree $2$ (positions for the vertex $1$) multiplied by $6!$ (for arranging the remaining $6$ vertices) and finally divided by the number of symmetries.

Comment: That is too large, the total number of trees of seven vertices is $7^5=16807$.

Comment: Yes, this looks good! The answer should be $8 \cdot 6! = 5760$ (holding vertex $1$ fix and varrying the other $6$)? I see, for each case we should calculate the possibilities seperately.

Comment: @AhmedHossam Vertex 1 is not fixed. Vertex $1$ is any vertex of degree $2$.

Comment: In the first case vertex $1$ could be any of the middle $5$ vertices. Fixing vertex $1$ and varrying the other $6$, we get $5 \cdot 6!$ possibilities in total. Why do you divide your first case by $2$?

Comment: Because in the first case the labelling $(2,1,3,4,5,6,7)$ is the same of the reversed one  $(7,6,5,4,3,1,2)$

Comment: Ok, nice work!!! What about case $7$? We have two vertices with degree $2$, so in total $2 \cdot 6!$ possible labellings. If the upper vertex is $1$, then we get $6!/2$ distinct trees, right?

Comment: Vertex $1$ has $2$ positions and we  permutate the 3 vertices of degree 1  at the bottom.

Comment: Okay, could you maybe loose some explanation about "how you think it in general" in your answer?

Comment: What do you mean? Maybe this page could be useful: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LabeledTree.html

Comment: Nice page! I mean, write in an edit to your answer how you arrived at the results for the different cases, like "what have you thought/imagined to get these answers for these cases"

Comment: These are standard computations. Anyway I prefer to wait for an OP's feedback, for now.

Comment: The only standard computation is labeling a vertex $v = 1$ in a tree case with $\deg(v)=2$ and counting $6! = 6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1$ different possibilities for the labeling of the tree with the other vertices $2,3,4,5,6$ and $7$

Comment: Ok, in case $4$ for example we get $3 \cdot 6!$ total possibilities for labeling the tree. Then we have to find out, which possibilities are equal. In this case, each $6!$ of the $3\cdot 6!$ possibilities is the same, because we can rotate the tree in case 4 around it's middle point. These $6!$ possibilities could be splitted into two exactly equal number of possibilities, because we can exchange the positions of the two labellings on the left and the two labellings on the right 'after the middle point'. Then we get $6!/2$. Maybe you could explain with some pictures, how it works and so on

Answer (score 0):

Since all degrees $\le 2$, the tree is actually a path.  The two vertices of degree $1$ have to go on the ends: wlog $2$ on the left and $3$ on the right, and the other five can be in any order.  So $5! = 120$ such trees.

Answer (score 0):

[In graph theory, a tree is an undirected graph in which any two vertices are connected by exactly one path, or equivalently a connected acyclic undirected graph.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory))

If $\deg(1)=2$, then we have $\binom{6}{2}=15$ ways of constructing/building the tree:

[image: possible combinations]

Each possibility could be extended to a tree.  Look at the $6$ vertices $v \in V'=\{2,3,4,5,6,7\}$. Two of them (doesn't matter which two in particular) are already connected with vertex $1$, these $v$ should have $\deg(v)<4 \Leftrightarrow \deg(v)\in\{1,2,3\}$. Four of them should have $\deg(v)<5 \Leftrightarrow \deg(v)\in\{1,2,3,4\}$.

So, the [degree sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory)#Degree_sequence) of the vertices $(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)$ would be $(2,b,c,d,e,f,g)$ with $1\leq b,c \leq 3$ and $1 \leq d,e,f,g, \leq 4$. Because we have $3^2\cdot4^4 =2304$ possible combinations for this degree sequence, there could be $2304$ possible trees, but for example a degree sequence like $(2,2,2,2,2,2,2)$

[image: No Tree]

(and some more) wouldn't be a tree, because this would contain cycles and a tree is defined to be acyclic or without cycles...

Answer (score 0):

You have one vertex of degree $2$ and there must be two pendant vertices. So you have four vertices left whose sum of degrees need to be $8$. Given the restrictions placed on the degrees, the only possible degrees of these vertices are $(2, 2, 2, 2)$, $(3, 2, 2, 1)$, $(3, 3, 1, 1)$ and $(4, 2, 1, 1)$. This gives the possible degree sequences as

- $(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1)$
- $(3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1)$
- $(3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1)$
- $(4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1)$

Now you will have to do some drawing to find that there is only one tree with first sequence, three trees with second sequence, and two trees each with third and fourth degree sequence. These are trees drawn in RobertZ answer.